# Adding a generic method constraint from the another generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm not sure the title reflect the question that I was meant, but..
Let's say I have two classes, `Entity` and `Component`:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    private List<Component> _components = new List<Component>();

    public void AddComponent<T>()
        where T : Component
    {
        T component = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        component.Owner = this;

        _components.Add(component);
    }
}

public abstract class Component
{
    public Entity Owner { get; protected set; }

    public abstract void Update();
}
```

As you may notice, above classes are `abstract classes` which mean is not intended for direct use. However, on the later stage of development, I'm aware that some `Component` require ability that only attachable / Added by specific class that inherited to `Entity` class.

So, I added a class `Component<T>` that inherit `Component`:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    private List<Component> _components = new List<Component>();

    public void AddComponent<T>()
        where T : Component
    {
        T component = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        component.Owner = this;

        _components.Add(component);
    }
}

public abstract class Component
{
    public Entity Owner { get; protected set; }

    public abstract void Update();
}

public abstract class Component<T> : Component
{
    // I hide the base.Owner with new keyword
    // feel free to suggest me in case there is better approach to do this
    new public T Owner 
    { 
        get { return (T)base.Owner; } 
        protected set { base.Owner = value; }
    }
}
```

And now, let's say I have `Foo`, `Bar` and `Processor` class:

```
public class Foo : Entity
{
    public int FooValue { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Entity
{
    public int BarValue { get; set; }
}

public class Processor : Component<Foo>
{
    public override void Update()
    {
        Owner.FooValue = 10;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to make `Processor` class only add-able by `Foo` object. Currently `AddComponent` ignore it, so I don't know how to do that:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();

foo.AddComponent<Processor>(); // OK
bar.AddComponent<Processor>(); // Compiler should give an error at this point
```

I also tried to do this:

```
public void AddComponent<T, X>()
    where T : Component<X>
    where X : Entity
{
    T component = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    component.Owner = this;

    _components.Add(component);
}
```

However, it require me to explicitly specify the X constraint:

```
foo.AddComponent<Processor, Foo>();
bar.AddComponent<Processor, Bar>(); // Error, but the syntax is weird!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your post isn't clear on what constraints, if any, you have on your basic `Entity` and `Component` classes. So I don't know if the below will be feasible in your scenario. That said, I believe that if it's not, you won't be able to do what you want because otherwise the generic type parameters won't be known by the compiler.

The solution, absent any other constraints, is to make your `Entity` class generic, and provide the sub-class type itself as the type parameter:

```
class Entity { }

class Entity<T> : Entity where T : Entity<T>
{
    public void AddComponent<U>(U value) where U : Component<T> { }
}

class Component<T> where T : Entity { }

class Foo : Entity<Foo> { }

class Bar : Entity<Bar> { }

class P : Component<Foo> { }
```

I know it looks weird. But you're basically asking for a self-referential graph of generic type dependencies, and in C# code the above is what that looks like.

You can call the `AddComponent()` method using type inference (so no generic parameter needed). If you try to call it with the wrong type of `Component<T>` object, you'll get a compiler error:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
P p = new P();

foo.AddComponent(p);
bar.AddComponent(p); // CS0311
```

Note: I would strongly recommend against hiding class members. It doesn't really affect your question as stated (i.e. you could have left that detail out completely), but having two different properties with the same name is just asking for bugs. If you *must* use hiding, IMHO you should at least have the new property use the hidden property. E.g.:

```
class Component
{
    public Entity Owner { get; protected set; }
}

class Component<T> : Component where T : Entity
{
    new public T Owner
    {
        get { return (T)base.Owner; }
        set { base.Owner = value; }
    }
}
```

You won't get compile-time checking on assignments to the non-generic `Component.Owner` property, but at least you'll get a run-time error if some code tries to dereference the `Owner` property as the generic version, if and when the wrong type was assigned by the base type for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's seems behave to something that i want it! However, there some cases that `Foo` or `Bar` is inherited with another class, Consider these 2 classes: `A : Foo` and `B : Bar` (and of course `Foo : Entity<Foo>` and `Bar : Entity<Bar>`), in such case, is it possible to create a `Component` that only attachable by class `B`?

Comment: Depends on what you mean precisely. You can make the base class generic (`class Foo<T> : Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>`), then you can specify the type parameter in the derived class: `class A : Foo<A>` and `class B : Foo<B>`. You can even make a non-generic version of `Foo`: `class Foo : Foo<Foo>`. The above should address your original stated concern. If you want to explore additional alternatives, I recommend you experiment with the above; if you run into trouble, you can always post a new question referencing this one.