# Strongly related classes and type safe abstractions

Tags: c#

I am designing a system that works with multiple data sources. These data sources have identifiers that can have certain checks done on them when they are created. It permits getting historical and real time data. My current abstraction involves three base classes.

The DataSource class is responsible for connections to services and maintaining esoteric things for that data source including how to open and close connections and thread safety concerns on a case by case basis.

The DataContext class is responsible for which values to get, be they realtime or historic and on what date etc, there may be other contexts where you could desire mixed historic dates (parameterized) among other things which is why I want to use polymorphism to accomplish this.

The Identifier class is responsible for parsing strings and validation against regular expressions to make sure that the string identifier that gets passed in is at least valid to some degree. It is also used for the type safety, because an identifier for one data source is not allowed to be passed into another data source.

See example code below;

```
public class DataSource
{
    // base class for all data sources
    // maintains connections opening and closing plus 
    // thread safety concerns
}
public class FooDataSource : DataSource { }

public class BarDataSource : DataSource { }

public abstract class Identifier
{
    public string Value { get; internal set; }

    public Identifier(string value)
    {
        Value = value; 
    }
}

public class FooIdentifier : Identifier
{
    public FooIdentifier(string value) : base(value)
    {
        // checks go here on the string that comes in 
        // specific to the foo data source
    }
}

public class BarIdentifier : Identifier
{
    public BarIdentifier(string value) : base(value)
    {
        // checks on the string values that come in for the Bar 
        // source 
    }
}


public abstract class DataContext<TIdentifier> where TIdentifier : Identifier
{
    public abstract double GetValue(TIdentifier id); 
}

public abstract class FooDataContext : DataContext<FooIdentifier> { }

public abstract class BarDataContext : DataContext<BarIdentifier> { }

public class FooRealTimeDataContext : FooDataContext
{
    public override double GetValue(FooIdentifier id)
    {
        // real implementation here 
        return -1; 
    }
}

public class BarRealTimeDataContext : BarDataContext
{
    public override double GetValue(BarIdentifier id)
    {
        // real implementation here
        return -10; 
    }
}


[TestFixture]
public static class TestMe
{
    [Test]
    public static void MyTest()
    {
        // create the data context (to get data from) 
        var ctx = new FooRealTimeDataContext();

        ctx.GetValue(new FooIdentifier("onetuhoenthuo")); // compiles (good)
        // ctx.GetValue(new BarIdentifier("noetuhneoth")); // does not compile (also good)
    }
}
```

**The question (finally)** is how do I create a class that actually follows OOP principals to fill in the following class shell?

```
public class UniversalRealTimeDataSource : DataSource<Identifier> {
    public double GetValue(Identifier id) {
        // there would have to be code in here that says "if(id is FooIdentifier) ... else ... 
        // which is (IMO) an anti-pattern so, how to avoid this? 
    }
}
```

Edit: I have been trying to keep the compile time type safety guarantees as much as possible. This would be fairly straightforward with some `if(!(id is FooIdentifier))` throw exception type of code but I want to make it impossible for this to occur at compile time.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, are you trying to find a way to relate FooDataSource and FooIdentifier at compile time, without having to check the type explicitly in your GetValue method?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but it _seems_ like you might be asking something similar to a question I answered earlier this week: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35979564. Your question might even be considered a duplicate of that one, though stated in a much more obscure way.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is a bit of a compromise in terms of compile time type safety. The Identifier selects its own data source from a menu of data sources (the universal data source). This prevents run-time errors unless the programmer uses the code incorrectly. Many things will probably be made private, the public layer will include all DataContext and Identifier subclasses.

```
public abstract class DataSource
{
    // base class for all data sources
    // maintains connections opening and closing plus 
    // thread safety concerns

    // these classes will most likely be private
    // maybe even within the universal data source class as inner classes

    // THE TWO METHODS BELOW ARE ONLY TO BE CALLED FROM WITHIN THE UniversalDataSource CLASS
    public abstract double GetRealTimeValue(Identifier id);

    public abstract double GetHistoricalValue(Identifier id, DateTime asof); 
}
public class FooDataSource : DataSource {
    public override double GetRealTimeValue(Identifier id)
    {
        return -1;
        // real implementation here, must be identifier type upcasting with runtime check
    }

    public override double GetHistoricalValue(Identifier id, DateTime asof)
    {
        return -2; 
        // real implementation here, must be identifier type upcasting with runtime check
    }
}

public class BarDataSource : DataSource {
    public override double GetRealTimeValue(Identifier id)
    {
        return -3; 
        // real implementation here, must be identifier type upcasting with runtime check
    }

    public override double GetHistoricalValue(Identifier id, DateTime asof)
    {
        return -4; 
        // real implementation here, must be identifier type upcasting with runtime check
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// holds initialized references to all possible data sources
/// </summary>
public class UniversalDataSource 
{

    public FooDataSource FooDS { get; internal set; }
    public BarDataSource BarDS { get; internal set; }

    public UniversalDataSource(FooDataSource fooDs, BarDataSource barDs)
    {
        this.FooDS = fooDs;
        this.BarDS = barDs;
    }

    public double GetRealTimeValue(Identifier id)
    {
        var specificDS = id.GetDataSource(this);
        return specificDS.GetRealTimeValue(id); 
    }

    public double GetHistoricalValue(Identifier id, DateTime asof)
    {
        var specificDS = id.GetDataSource(this);
        return specificDS.GetHistoricalValue(id, asof); 
    }
}

public abstract class Identifier
{
    public string Value { get; internal set; }

    public Identifier(string value)
    {
        Value = value; 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the appropriate data source for THIS kind of identifier (abstractly)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="universalDataSource"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public abstract DataSource GetDataSource(UniversalDataSource universalDataSource); 
}

public class FooIdentifier : Identifier
{
    public FooIdentifier(string value) : base(value)
    {
        // checks go here on the string that comes in 
        // specific to the foo data source
    }

    public override DataSource GetDataSource(UniversalDataSource universalDataSource)
    {
        return universalDataSource.FooDS; 
    }
}

public class BarIdentifier : Identifier
{
    public BarIdentifier(string value) : base(value)
    {
        // checks on the string values that come in for the Bar 
        // source 
    }

    public override DataSource GetDataSource(UniversalDataSource universalDataSource)
    {
        return universalDataSource.BarDS; 
    }
}


public abstract class DataContext
{
    public UniversalDataSource DataSource { get; internal set; }

    protected DataContext(UniversalDataSource dataSource)
    {
        DataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public abstract double GetValue(Identifier id); 
}

public class RealTimeDataContext : DataContext {

    public RealTimeDataContext(UniversalDataSource dataSource) : base(dataSource)
    {
    }

    public override double GetValue(Identifier id)
    {
        return DataSource.GetRealTimeValue(id); 
    }
}

public class HistoricalDataContext : DataContext {

    public DateTime AsOf { get; internal set; }

    public HistoricalDataContext(UniversalDataSource dataSource, DateTime asof) : base(dataSource)
    {
        AsOf = asof; 
    }

    public override double GetValue(Identifier id)
    {
        return DataSource.GetHistoricalValue(id, AsOf); 
    }

}

[TestFixture]
public static class TestMe
{
    [Test]
    public static void MyTest()
    {
        // create the data context (to get data from) 
        var ds = new UniversalDataSource(
            new FooDataSource(),
            new BarDataSource()
            );

        var realTimeDataContext = new RealTimeDataContext(ds);
        var historicalDataContext = new HistoricalDataContext(ds, DateTime.MinValue);

        var fooId = new FooIdentifier("onetuhoenthuo");
        var barId = new BarIdentifier("onetuhoenthuo"); 

        // testing dispatch
        Assert.AreEqual(-1, realTimeDataContext.GetValue(fooId));
        Assert.AreEqual(-2, historicalDataContext.GetValue(fooId));
        Assert.AreEqual(-3, realTimeDataContext.GetValue(barId));
        Assert.AreEqual(-4, historicalDataContext.GetValue(barId)); 

    }
}
```

Perhaps this solution will clear up what I have been trying to do from the start. The reason for the data context class to even exist is due to working with financial data, weekends and holidays can cause NA values and shuffling dates for different identifiers may make sense in a historical data request setting. These strategies will be implemented polymorphically by overriding the `GetValue` methods.